# Datagrid returns a null value, can I replace this?

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, null, advanceddatagrid

Hi I have an Advanced Datagrid in flex and on occasions the query that populates this graph will return an empty cell value. when this happens the Datagrid displays "NaN". is there anyway that if my query doesn't return anything the Datagrid cell just remains blank.

thanks
mxml:
'

```
                    <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="{Mlc.curr.get('address')}" dataField="datafield2" width="{Math.max(180,getStyle('fontSize')))}" />
                    <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="{Mlc.curr.get('Name')}" dataField="datafield1" width="{Math.max(180,getStyle('fontSize')))}" />


                </components:columns>
                </components:RowColorDataGrid>
```

'

as:

```
accountViewGridCanv.numRows = 1000;
 dgGridCanv.addParameter(Constants.parameter,""); 
 dgGridCanv.itemID = displayItems.indexOf(dgGrid);
```

basically a query runs to a spreadsheet and results are displayed in a datagrid, but if the cell in the spreadsheet is null then the datagrid displays "NaN"

Thanks
Again

Comment: Please share some code.  It sounds like your DataGrid's dataProvider has an item in it; but we need to know how your processing those results from the service and setting the dataProvider to know for sure.

Comment: Try manage the labelFunction of column.

Comment: Thanks I have used the code to be able to remove the NaN from the datagrid but it removes every row in that column. e.g rows 1 and 2 are null but 3 contains a valid number. In this situation all 3 rows return 0. is it possible to have this apply to just rows with NaN

Answer (score 0):

This happens when the webservice returns null for a Number datatype. Flex converts it into NaN(Not a Number). Use labelfunction to check if the value in the column is NaN or not. If it is, then return appropriate value to display.eg-

```
<mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="Quantity" labelFunction="getTotalQty"/>
```

now check for NaN in the getTotalQty function

```
private function getTotalQty(inData:Object, inCol:AdvancedDataGridColumn):Number
    {
        return (isNaN(inData.qty)?0:inData.qty);
    }
```

Comment: if you have a close look at my getTotalQty function, it returns the actual value of the data if it is not NaN. So, you should not get 0 in all rows unless you have not implemented the function correctly or the actual data in the row was 0 already.

Comment: also, replace the datatype of the inData argument from Object to the datatype of your object in the dataprovider. Hope this helps..

Comment: hi, this definetely does not work. the item in my advanced datagrid as an object but this returns 0 for all rows in that column irrespective of what has been returned in the data provider. it has been implemented exactly as it is here